# What type of connector / terminal end is this?

Tags: relay, connector

This wire comes off a automotive multi-pin relay block/connector housing. Requesting help to identify what type/name of connector it is. -Thanks

[image: Undetermined connector type]

Answer (score 4):

Crimped female spade terminal?
They are available at any hardware store.

Answer (score 0):

Female 1/4" tab terminal - one trade name is "Faston".  Should be available in auto supply shops, hardware stores, marine supply...

Comment: Appreciate it. That certainly looks to be it.